# Jenkins pipeline failing based on executed batch file exit code

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins-pipeline, pycodestyle

I have a jenkins stage that will check all the .py files in the repo according to the pycodestyle standard.

For this purpose I am using a .bat file to execute this command. But, if the exit code for the batch file is not 0, the jenkins pipeline will also stop. Is there any way, I can continue the jenkins pipeline execution irrespective of what the exit code is for my batch file?

right now my stage looks something like this.

```
pycodestyle: {
    powershell"""
    .\\venv\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1
    ${WORKSPACE}\\code_analyzer\\check_pycodestyle.bat 2>&1 | tee pycodestyle.log
    """
```

The output of the batch file looks something like this.

```
[2023-04-03T09:20:23.748Z] 

[2023-04-03T09:20:23.748Z] _PR-27>pycodestyle --exclude venv,mfile,resource_rc.py --config=_PR-27\code_analyzer\\pep8.config _PR-27\code_analyzer\\.. 

[2023-04-03T09:20:23.748Z] _PR-27\code_analyzer\\..\release\whl_release.py:47:1: E402 module level import not at top of file

[2023-04-03T09:20:24.009Z] _PR-27\code_analyzer\\..\tests\system\test_utils_build_and_install.py:31:1: E402 module level import not at top of file

[2023-04-03T09:20:24.269Z] _PR-27\code_analyzer\\..\utils\helper.py:45:1: W391 blank line at end of file

script returned exit code 1
```

I want to continue the execution of the jenkins pipeline even after the exit code is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KiiroiSenko's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75926897/45375) points to a *Jenkins* solution.

The problem can more simply be solved on the *PowerShell* side, however - just **add `exit 0`** as the last statement:

```
    powershell"""
    .\\venv\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1
    ${WORKSPACE}\\code_analyzer\\check_pycodestyle.bat 2>&1 | tee pycodestyle.log
    exit 0
    """
```

That is:

- You're invoking [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, with the **implied `-Command` parameter**, which accepts one or more PowerShell statements to execute, and determines the exit code to report to its caller as follows:
- Unless you use an `exit` statement to control the process exit code *explicitly*, it is the *success status* of the *last* statement executed that *implicitly* determines the exit code, based on the value of the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1):

  - If `$?` is `$true`, indicating a successful statement outcome, the process exit code becomes `0`; otherwise, it is `1`.<sup>[1]</sup>

    - Note that it is `1` even if the last statement is an external-program call that reported a *different* nonzero exit code, as reflected in [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)
  - Therefore:

    - If you want **to report the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`, to relay the specific exit code reported by the most recently executed external program**, use **`exit $LASTEXITCODE`**
    - Conversely - as in your case - if you want **to *unconditionally* signal success** to the caller by setting `0` as the exit code, use **`exit 0`**
- Note that if you were to use the **`-File` CLI parameter** instead of `-Command` - so as to invoke a script *file* (`*.ps1`), the exit-code logic changes:

  - Only *explicit* `exit` calls specifying an exit code are honored.
  - Otherwise:

    - Irrespective of whether errors occurred during the script's execution, exit code `0` is reported.
    - *Except* if a *fatal* (script-terminating) error occurs, in which case `1` is reported.

      - A fatal error occurs when script invocation fails fundamentally (due to syntax errors or the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) preventing script execution, for instance) or when one is triggered explicitly by the script, via a `throw` statement or via the [`-ErrorAction Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) common parameter or the [`$ErrorActionPrefererence = 'Stop'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) preference variable.

For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

---

<sup>[1] If a statement is a call to an *external program* or involves one as part of the pipeline and no other commands in the pipeline signal an error condition, its process exit code, as reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE`, determines the value of `$?`: `0` sets `$?` to `$true`, and any nonzero value sets it to `$false`.

In *Windows PowerShell* (but no longer in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)), `$false` can (inappropriately) also result even with an exit code of `0`, namely if a `2>&1` redirection is present *and* there is actual stderr output.</sup>

Comment: I tried with ```exit 0``` the problem with this is, I believe that it will set the exit code to 0 but since it is exiting the powershell completely, the following stages in the jenkinsfile will never be executed. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @programmer_04_03, a `powershell.exe` CLI call with either (possibly implied) `-Command` or `-File` _always_ exits - whether you use `exit` or not: the specified statements / script is executed, and the process terminates (the only exception is if you also pass `-NoExit`, which you obviously shouldn't do in a CI/CD environment). In other words: `exit 0` should do what you want, without unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in a catchError step or use a basic try-catch block, (if using scripted syntax).

More info on this [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/) url.

Comment: just using try and catch and changing the status of the ```currentBuild.status = 'SUCCESS'``` worked. Thank you for the link and suggestion @KiiroiSenko